# How to automatically select the cells to which the formulas of a cell are related?

Tags: excel, select, cell

If a cell contains a value say '=a3', is there any way to automatically select a3? or if the cell related to 2 cells, both the cells has to be selected and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Want you want is only possible for certain formulas.  For example:

```
=Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1
```

references cells on two different worksheets.  It is not possible to simultaneously **Select** cells on different worksheets.

Comment: yes, but if they refer to the cells of same sheet?? trace reference is one of the way but i am searching for a shorter method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got a shorter method. Shortcut key to **trace references**. If you want to trace preceding reference press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and if you want to find out which cells are referred to the current cells, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have already answered your question, but another option that will do what you originally asked, ie selecting cells: Go to File>Options>Advanced untick 'Allow editing directly in cells'. Now if you double click on a cell with a formula in, it will select the relevant cell(s).